# Sublime Text 2 Snippet escaping backslash

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to set up a snippet for building a set with appropriate spacing. I want the snippet to generate the following markup when I type "set" + TAB:

```
\{ \, content here \, \}
```

I have the following snippet:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
\{\, ${1} \,\}
]]></content>
<tabTrigger>set</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

However, this produces the following:

```
{\,  \,}
```

It's escaping the first backslash and the last one. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Can you provide some additional information like which editor you are using etc?

Comment: Sublime Text 2 on OS X.

Comment: I don't know which language uses, but usually you need `\\{\, ${1} \,\\}` to avoid escaping the backslash. Try an look if it works. (In TextMate, for example, it works that way.)

Comment: Bingo, that works. If you'd like to submit that as the answer, I'll mark it.

Comment: @Manuel Can you turn your comment into an answer, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: I turned this into an answer following @egreg 's suggestion. This is not a very clear/correct answer (I let anyone to edit and correct it), but based (only) on my experience in TextMate.*

You need to avoid escaping the backslash, which is “usually” done with `\\{\, ${1} \,\\}`.